# Select script for data with closest date and an ID as a tie breaker

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is a script to generate sample data from which I need to write a select statement to return one PlanID per CareID. The PlanID needs to have the AgreedDate or the MDTDate that is closest to the DiagnosisDate. In the case of multiples the highest value PlanID is the tie breaker. It doesn't matter if the closest date is before or after the DiagnosisDate. Thank you.

```
create table ClosestDate
(CareID int not null, PlanID int not null, 
PerformanceStatus int not null, DiagnosisDate date null,
AgreedDate date null, MDTDate date null)

insert into ClosestDate values (1,1833,2,'12/07/2013','20/08/2011','20/08/2011')
insert into ClosestDate values (4,65,3,'28/07/2009','27/11/2009','27/11/2009')
insert into ClosestDate values (7,68,0,'19/09/2009','22/09/2009','09/12/2009')
insert into ClosestDate values (8,69,2,'30/10/2009','15/12/2009','15/12/2009')
insert into ClosestDate values (9,64,1,'02/10/2009','18/11/2009','18/11/2009')
insert into ClosestDate values (23,278,1,'21/07/2009','15/09/2009','15/09/2009')
insert into ClosestDate values (63,66,1,'19/07/2009','27/03/2010','27/03/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (70,40,0,'24/03/2010','23/03/2010','23/03/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (106,67,1,'27/08/2009','04/04/2010','05/04/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (109,72,1,'10/12/2009','06/01/2010','06/01/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (110,74,3,'13/12/2009','15/01/2010','08/01/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (111,57,1,'01/09/2009','03/11/2009','03/11/2009')
insert into ClosestDate values (149,1640,1,'05/07/2011','05/07/2011','05/07/2011')
insert into ClosestDate values (199,110,1,'12/01/2010','20/02/2010',NULL)
insert into ClosestDate values (205,73,1,'14/12/2009','08/02/2010','08/02/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (209,109,3,'15/01/2010','09/02/2010',NULL)
insert into ClosestDate values (222,104,4,'26/03/2010','06/04/2010','06/04/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (222,105,3,'26/03/2010','08/04/2010','08/04/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (222,106,1,'26/03/2010','09/04/2010','09/04/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (222,111,3,'26/03/2010','09/04/2010','09/04/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (228,136,3,'02/04/2010','07/07/2010','07/07/2010')
insert into ClosestDate values (304,4054,2,'11/06/2013','11/06/2013','11/06/2013')
insert into ClosestDate values (304,5151,1,'11/06/2013','17/03/2014','17/03/2014')
insert into ClosestDate values (305,1507,2,'14/10/2010','14/05/2011','14/05/2011')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I had to reformat your data in order to be able to convert it to `date` type. I did it manually so there might be errors in here but the logic of the query should not be affected. Reformatted code:

```
create table #ClosestDate
(CareID int not null, PlanID int not null, 
PerformanceStatus int not null, DiagnosisDate date null,
AgreedDate date null, MDTDate date null)

insert into #ClosestDate values (1,1833,2,  '20130712', '20110820', '20110820')
insert into #ClosestDate values (4,65,3,    '20090728', '20091127', '20091127')
insert into #ClosestDate values (7,68,0,    '20090919', '20090922', '20091209')
insert into #ClosestDate values (8,69,2,    '20091030', '20091215', '20091215')
insert into #ClosestDate values (9,64,1,    '20091002', '20091118', '20091118')
insert into #ClosestDate values (23,278,1,  '20090721', '20090915', '20090915')
insert into #ClosestDate values (63,66,1,   '20090719', '20100327', '20100327')
insert into #ClosestDate values (70,40,0,   '20100324', '20100323', '20100323')
insert into #ClosestDate values (106,67,1,  '20090827', '20100404', '20100405')
insert into #ClosestDate values (109,72,1,  '20091210', '20100106', '20100106')
insert into #ClosestDate values (110,74,3,  '20091213', '20100115', '20100108')
insert into #ClosestDate values (111,57,1,  '20090901', '20091103', '20091103')
insert into #ClosestDate values (149,1640,1,'20110705', '20110705', '20110705')
insert into #ClosestDate values (199,110,1, '20100112', '20100220', NULL)
insert into #ClosestDate values (205,73,1,  '20091214', '20100208', '20100208')
insert into #ClosestDate values (209,109,3, '20100115', '20100209', NULL)
insert into #ClosestDate values (222,104,4, '20100326', '20100406', '20100406')
insert into #ClosestDate values (222,105,3, '20100326', '20100408', '20100408')
insert into #ClosestDate values (222,106,1, '20100326', '20100409', '20100409')
insert into #ClosestDate values (222,111,3, '20100326', '20100409', '20100409')
insert into #ClosestDate values (228,136,3, '20100402', '20100707', '20100707')
insert into #ClosestDate values (304,4054,2,'20130611', '20130611', '20130611')
insert into #ClosestDate values (304,5151,1,'20130611', '20140317', '20140317')
insert into #ClosestDate values (305,1507,2,'20101014', '20110514', '20110514')
```

Here's my proposed solution:

```
; WITH Differences AS (
    -- calculate the differences in days
    SELECT CareID, PlanID, PerformanceStatus, DiagnosisDate, AgreedDate, MDTDate
        , CASE
            -- if any of the dates is null, take the difference to the other one or NULL if both are NULL
            WHEN AgreedDate IS NULL OR MDTDate IS NULL THEN COALESCE(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DiagnosisDate, AgreedDate)), ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DiagnosisDate, MDTDate)))
            -- take the smaller difference (WHEN AND ELSE cover this logic)
            WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DiagnosisDate, AgreedDate)) <= ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DiagnosisDate, MDTDate)) THEN ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DiagnosisDate, AgreedDate))
            ELSE ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DiagnosisDate, MDTDate))
          END AS SmallerDiffInDays
    FROM #ClosestDate
), SmallestDifferencesPlanIDPerCareID AS (
    SELECT CareID, PlanID, PerformanceStatus,
        -- partition the data by CareID, order it by SmallerDiffInDays ascending and as a tie-breaker use PlanID DESC
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CareID ORDER BY SmallerDiffInDays, PlanID DESC) AS RwNr
    FROM Differences
)
SELECT CareID, PlanID, PerformanceStatus
FROM SmallestDifferencesPlanIDPerCareID
WHERE RwNr = 1;
```

The code snippet has comments that should explain what I was doing in the above query and why.

The output of the query is:

```
CareID  | PlanID    | PerformanceStatus
1       | 1833      | 2
4       | 65        | 3
7       | 68        | 0
8       | 69        | 2
9       | 64        | 1
23      | 278       | 1
63      | 66        | 1
70      | 40        | 0
106     | 67        | 1
109     | 72        | 1
110     | 74        | 3
111     | 57        | 1
149     | 1640      | 1
199     | 110       | 1
205     | 73        | 1
209     | 109       | 3
222     | 104       | 4
228     | 136       | 3
304     | 4054      | 2
305     | 1507      | 2
```

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: sorry about the formatting issue, it seemed to work ok on my schema. your script returns the required results and this is what i will be using. this is for a real scenario to be applied in a professional environment. thank you for taking the time to work on this - especially on a Sunday!

Comment: It was probably just due to the differences in collations (cultures) between my instance and yours. It's all fine as long as the query is what you were looking for. Glad to have helped out :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest way i could come up with, it involves adding a new column to the table, if you don't want to alter table structure, i advise you use temptables

```
alter table ClosestDate add MinDateDiff bigint;

update ClosestDate Set MinDateDiff = (Case 
                            When ABS(DATEDIFF(DD,DiagnosisDate, AgreedDate)) < ABS(DATEDIFF(DD,DiagnosisDate, MDTDate)) 
                            Then ABS(DATEDIFF(DD,DiagnosisDate, AgreedDate)) 
                            When MDTDate is null 
                            Then ABS(DATEDIFF(DD,DiagnosisDate, AgreedDate)) 
                            Else ABS(DATEDIFF(DD,DiagnosisDate, MDTDate)) 
                        End);

Select a.CareID, Max(PlanID) PlanID
from ClosestDate a
inner join (Select CareID, Min(MinDateDiff) MinDateDiff
from ClosestDate
group by CareID) as b on a.CareID = b.CareID and a.MinDateDiff = b.MinDateDiff
group by a.CareID;
```

Comment: although your script does return the required results, the extra derived values do affect the performance in profiler so if i can get the results without the extra columns i will. thank you for your help, it's much appreciated